# Setup breaking in Selenium project in Jenkins but all tests passing

Tags: java, git, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I have a Selenium Java UI automation freestyle project setup at my local Jenkins and after building it I am facing the error, "Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. The current browser version is 116.0.5845.96."

Due to this error, my setup step is breaking which is eventually making the build unstable but all my tests are passing.

Attaching the setup step error and the console output as well below:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome 
Host info: host: 'Vishals-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '2405:201:401d:e834:1d4e:a572:5d7c:4fae%en0'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.4', java.version: '11.0.20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at com.qa.opencart.factory.DriverFactory.initDriver(DriverFactory.java:47)
    at com.qa.opencart.base.BaseTest.setup(BaseTest.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


    Started by user Vishal Pamnani
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/vishalpamnani/November2022POMSeriesCode # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/vishalpamnani/November2022POMSeriesCode
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/vishalpamnani/November2022POMSeriesCode +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e1430e2a702e3c86527088e040790422dcc3ca48 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e1430e2a702e3c86527088e040790422dcc3ca48 # timeout=10
Commit message: "added set browser version code in options manager"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 4e661f14c03d38eca0bccbcad65fa7d84e4d500b # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 57753
[OpenCart Automation Job] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java -cp /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.14.jar:/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3107.v665000b_51092.jar /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 57753
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< Naveen2023POMSeries:Naveen2023POMSeries >---------------
[INFO] Building Naveen2023POMSeries 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from src/test/resources to target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

I am in onStart method Login Page Test
Test Suite started!
Browser Name is: chrome
Aug 23, 2023 4:15:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 115
I am in onTestStart method loginPageTitleTeststart
loginPageTitleTeststarted!
Login page title is: Account Login
I am in onTestSuccess method loginPageTitleTestsucceeded
loginPageTitleTestpassed!
I am in onTestStart method loginPageURLTeststart
loginPageURLTeststarted!
Login page url is: https://naveenautomationlabs.com/opencart/index.php?route=account/login
I am in onTestSuccess method loginPageURLTestsucceeded
loginPageURLTestpassed!
I am in onTestStart method forgotPasswordLinkExistTeststart
forgotPasswordLinkExistTeststarted!
I am in onTestSuccess method forgotPasswordLinkExistTestsucceeded
forgotPasswordLinkExistTestpassed!
I am in onTestStart method loginTeststart
loginTeststarted!
App credentials are: best@yopmail.com : Trying@123
I am in onTestSuccess method loginTestsucceeded
loginTestpassed!
I am in onFinish method Login Page Test
Test Suite is ending!
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.816 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ Naveen2023POMSeries ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/pom.xml to /Users/vishalpamnani/.m2/repository/Naveen2023POMSeries/Naveen2023POMSeries/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/vishalpamnani/.m2/repository/Naveen2023POMSeries/Naveen2023POMSeries/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.469 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-23T16:15:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/pom.xml to Naveen2023POMSeries/Naveen2023POMSeries/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/target/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to Naveen2023POMSeries/Naveen2023POMSeries/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Naveen2023POMSeries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
[OpenCart Automation Job] $ /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/allure/bin/allure generate "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history" "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-results/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history/history" -c -o "/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-report"
Report successfully generated to /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/workspace/OpenCart Automation Job/reports to /Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/jobs/OpenCart Automation Job/builds/16/htmlreports/Extent_20HTML_20Report
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Saving reports...
Processing '/Users/vishalpamnani/.jenkins/jobs/OpenCart Automation Job/builds/16/testng/testng-results.xml'
TestNG Reports Processing: FINISH
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

So your logs state:

> Aug 23, 2023 4:15:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder
> findNearestMatch WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP
> version 116, so returning the closest version found: 115

This means you need to update your Selenium dependancy, it's not only your browser version that is in play here.

As you can see in the [last two release notes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG), I am guessing that you are running `v4.11.0` of Selenium, you might need to wait for version `v4.12.0` if it's not available yet to get support for `CDP version 116`...

> ## v4.12.0
>
> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 114, 115, 116
>
> ## v4.11.0
>
> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 113, 114, 115

Comment: Yes, I am running v4.11.0 of Selenium. So are you suggesting that I should downgrade my browser to 115?

Comment: If all your tests are passing and things are stable you could wait until the next release of Selenium as this could just remain a warning for a while. If things are really unstable it would probably be best to try and go back one version of Chrome.